# If $A$ is a $k$-algebra for an algebraically closed field $k$, then $A/M=k$ for any maximal $M$ of $A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am trying to understand why if a commutative ring $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra for an algebraically closed field $k$, then $A/M=k$ for any maximal $M$ of $A$.

I know that by the Nullstellensatz that $A/M$ is a finite field extension of $k$, and that we have the homomorphism $k\rightarrow A\rightarrow A/M$. However, how can I use the algebraic closure of $k$ to see that this is indeed an isomorphism?

Comment: $k\to A/M$ is clearly injective as $k$ is a field. Now if $k$ is algebraically closed, so is the image of $k'$ of $k$ under the map $k\to A/M$. Since $A/M$ is a finite extension of $k'$ we have $k'=A/M$ because $k'$ is algebraically closed (finite implies algebraic). Therefore $k\to A/M$ surjective, hence an isomorphism.

Comment: Is it just me, or is it intended that $A$ is commutative, and finitely generated as an algebra over $k$?

Comment: In algebraic geometry usually rings are understood as commutative unless otherwise stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A/M$ is a finite field extension of $k$, and is in particular algebraic over $k$.  But $k$ is algebraically closed, so $A/M = k$.